# Visual Studio Profiler

Tags: отладка, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

Есть очень большой asp.net проект. В котором есть около 100 dll-к. На сайте происходит некоторое действие. Есть ли возможность посмотреть деревья вызовов методов из указанных библиотек, не прибегая к стандартной отладке. Произвести отладку для каждой библиотеки отдельно не представляется возможным.

Точно знаю что в SQL Server есть инструмент '**Profiler**' который выводит список всех вызванных сохраненок, хотелось бы что то типа этого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень удобный инструмент для профилирования под названием dotTracer от jetBrains. Позволяет посмотреть не только деревья вызовов, но и время работы каждого метода, найти узкие места и тд. Можно трейсить не только вебные приложения. Вообщем не представляю без него оптимизации приложений, особенно больших. Единственный минус - он платный, как и остальные продукты данной компании, но найти его взломанным не представляет труда.

Comment: Спасибо. Именно то что нужно